# Как мне на js создать json файл и сохранить туда данные, которые мне пришли с сервера?

Tags: javascript, json

Как мне на js создать json файл и сохранить туда данные, которые мне пришли с сервера?

Я сделал запрос на сервер и мне пришел объект с данными и нужно эти данные записать в отдельный файл json формата.

Comment: js бывает разный, о чём конкретно речь? Node или браузер?

Comment: Браузер скорее всего, точно

Comment: Из браузера создавать файлы невозможно по соображениям безопасности

Comment: А если из node, то можно как-то сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2496710

Comment: @Roman, посмотрите модуль [fs](https://nodejsdev.ru/api/fs/)

Answer (score 1):

Если устраивает появление диалога для сохранения файла то можно сделать с помощью библиотеки [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver). В качестве аргументов  функция saveAs принимает `blob` и имя файла. Blob cоздается через экземпляр `Blob` в конструктор которого передаются данные (строка) и тип файла в данном случае `application/json` так же иногда не лишне будет передача `charset` для того чтобы не поломалась кодировка. Код приведенный ниже отработает если его перенести в html файл, в снипете вероятно по причине безопасности некоторый код не отрабатывает.

`JSON.stringify(json, null, 2)` - форматирует json с табуляцией в 2 пробела

```html
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.0/FileSaver.min.js" integrity="sha512-csNcFYJniKjJxRWRV1R7fvnXrycHP6qDR21mgz1ZP55xY5d+aHLfo9/FcGDQLfn2IfngbAHd8LdfsagcCqgTcQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <style></style>
  </head>
  <body>
     <script>
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => saveAs(
            new Blob(
              [JSON.stringify(json, null, 2)],
              {type: "application/json;charset=" + document.characterSet}
          ), "doc.json")
        )
     </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```